# Problems with facebook app's web-hook

Tags: facebook

An application in FB was created and a web-hook is configured in it.
here is the code of the host script -

```
echo $_REQUEST['hub_challenge'];
define( "LOG_FILENAME", $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/log2.txt");
AddMessage2Log($_REQUEST);
```

here i'm sending back confirmation token to initialize web-hook and want add to log $_REQUEST. (loging works normally)

when initializing the web hook - the data arrived! -

```
'hub_mode' => 'subscribe',
'hub_challenge' => '696447250',
'hub_verify_token' => '123',
```

After  that - I send the test data from FaceBook App in web-hook's settings http://prntscr.com/gsrjub  and  should get them  at my host. But  they do not come!! I do as written in the FB documentation

here is the screen of log file (loging REQUEST) http://prntscr.com/gsrkmw

Can someone tell me, am I doing something wrong? ;)

Thx 4 ur time

Comment: Facebook send the data as `Content-Type: application/json`, so you will _not_ find it in $_REQUEST or $_POST ...

Comment: so how i can access this data in php in my script??

Comment: Read the duplicate ...

Comment: Thanks a lot bro)